# Advanced Placeholder in PUG with Express

Tags: node.js, templates, express, pug, placeholder

I know how the standard Placeholdersystem in PUG works.

```
res.render('index', { title: 'Chat'}
```

will be in `#{title}`

I also get my Object from an API into it, like

```
res.render('index', { title: 'Chat', name: obj[1].pseudo});
```

works as `#{name}`

But here comes my Problem.

I'd like to have Placeholders in PUG like `#{user:6:name}` and it will be `obj[6]pseudo`

Is there a way get things done like this?

Or another?
I 've got like 60 Profile datas that i'd like to use so flexible as possible in the template.

Here is my index.js

```
    /* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    Request.get("https://cmediaapi.datingpartner.com/content/v3_real/profiles", (error, response, data) => {
      if(error) {
          return console.dir(error);
      }
      // console.dir(JSON.parse(data));
      obj = JSON.parse(data);
      // console.dir(obj[1].pseudo);
      res.render('index', { title: 'Chat', name: obj[1].pseudo});
    });
});
```

Thanks a lot for your help and ideas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pug [interpolation](https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html) uses Javascript expressions.

When passing the locals as:

```
res.render('index', { title: 'Chat', name: obj });
```

Use the standard javascript accessor:

```
#{name[1].pseudo}
```

Comment: Works! Thanks a lot!

Exactly what i was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

I also find out this that could be helpfull in other Situations.

When you want to have a special amount of user ids in a loop.

This example starts at user id 10 and ends at user id 40.

```
ul#list
        //- li.user #{user[2].pseudo}       
        each user in obj.slice(10, 40)
            li(class='user')
                div.thumb
                    img(src='https://images.url.com/' + user.image_300x300)
                div.info(onclick="location.href=\'/user/" + user.pseudo + "?" + ref + "'")
                    p= user.pseudo
                    p #{user.age} Jahre | #{user.city}
```